# Calling PL/SQL procedure from ant script does not run the stored procedure

Tags: oracle, ant, plsql, sqlplus

I am calling a PL/SQL procedure from an ant script. In the output window it is displaying "build successful", but the stored procedure `proc.sql` does not execute.

Here is my build script:

```
<target name="DATA">

 <property name="oracle.scriptPath" value="D:\\ganganshu" />

 <property name="oracle.tns_alias2" value="wind"/>
 <!-- Oracle user name -->
 <property name="oracle.user_name2" value="SILO2" />
 <!-- Oracle Password -->
 <property name="oracle.password2" value="SILO2" />

 <exec executable="sqlplus" failonerror="true">
  <arg value="${oracle.user_name2}/${oracle.password2}@${oracle.tns_alias2}"/>
  <arg value="@${oracle.scriptPath}\\ELEM10_ELEM_PHX_WTPART.sql"/>
  <arg value="@${oracle.scriptPath}\\proc.sql"/>
 </exec>

</target>
```

My stored procedure is:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE ELEM10_ELEM_PHX_ATT_WTPART
AS
CURSOR targ_dest_relation IS
    SELECT sourcecolumn  FROM mapping where destinationtable='ATT_WTPART';
BEGIN

DECLARE
source_Table varchar2(255) := 'ELEM10_ELEM_PHX';
destination_Table varchar2(255) := 'ATT_WTPART';
src_Column varchar2(255);
src_Type varchar2(255);
src_Type_Value varchar2(255);
src_Name varchar2(255);
src_Name_Value varchar2(255);
dest_Column varchar2(255);
dest_Column_Value varchar2(255);
query1 varchar2(255);

BEGIN

    FOR rec IN targ_dest_relation loop
           dbms_output.put_line('destination_Table: ' || destination_Table);
           dbms_output.put_line('source_Table: ' || source_Table);

           src_Column :=  rec.sourcecolumn;
           dbms_output.put_line('src_Column: ' || src_Column);

           src_Type := 'select data_type from user_tab_columns where 
           table_name ='''||source_Table||'''and column_name='''|| 
           src_Column ||'''';
           dbms_output.put_line('src_Type: ' || src_Type);

           execute immediate src_Type INTO src_Type_Value;
           dbms_output.put_line('src_Type_Value: ' || src_Type_Value);

           dest_Column := 'select DEST_COLUMN from ATT_TABLE_MAPPING where 
           SOURCETYPE='''|| src_Type_Value || '''';
           dbms_output.put_line('dest_Column: '  || dest_Column);

           execute immediate dest_Column INTO dest_Column_Value;
           dbms_output.put_line('dest_Column_Value: ' || dest_Column_Value);

           src_Name := 'select column_name from user_tab_columns where 
           table_name ='''|| source_Table ||'''  and column_name= ''' || 
           src_Column || '''';
           dbms_output.put_line('src_Name: ' || src_Name);

           execute immediate src_Name INTO src_Name_Value;
           dbms_output.put_line('src_Name_Value: ' || src_Name_Value);

           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || destination_Table || ' (IBANAME,' ||
           dest_Column_Value || ') SELECT :name,' || src_Column || 
           ' FROM ' || source_Table  USING src_Name_Value;

    END loop;  
END;
END;
```

Why does this not run the stored procedure?

Comment: that is just the definition of the procedure, where do you call it?

Comment: that is my question ..I need to call it from ant script so how to call it is my question

Comment: in the build.xml file I need to call which is given on the top.

Comment: you can call it at the end of your .sql script

Comment: how can u pls tell me..bec this stament <arg value="EXECUTE ELEM10_ELEM_PHX_WTPART.sql"/> is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Ant script you're trying to execute two files with one `sqlplus` execution, but that doesn't work. `sqlplus` just executes the first file and ignores the second one. If you want to have the creation of the procedure and the execution in two different files you have to run `sqplus` twice. Otherwise your Ant script looks ok for me.

Here is an example how to create, execute and drop a procedure with a single `sqlplus` run.

Everything is in file `foo.sql`:

```
$ cat foo.sql 
-- just for demonstration with dbms_output
set serveroutput on

-- create procedure
create or replace procedure foo is
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Hello!');
end;
/
show errors

-- execute procedure
exec foo

-- remove procedure
drop procedure foo;

-- exit sqlplus
exit
```

`sqlplus` execution:

```
$ sqlplus -L joe/joe @foo.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Dec 17 16:31:20 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production


Procedure created.

No errors.
Hello!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


Procedure dropped.

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 -     64bit Production
$
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add at the end:

```
/
EXECUTE ELEM10_ELEM_PHX_ATT_WTPART;
/
```

Comment: getting the same result

Comment: putting this in the end <arg value="EXECUTE ELEM10_ELEM_PHX_WTPART.sql"/>

Comment: no, put my code at the end of the .sql file or just `EXECUTE ELEM10_ELEM_PHX_ATT_WTPART;` in a second .sql script

Comment: I put this in 2nd file proc.sql and added it in the code as an argument but no change